# how i fix Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in undefined in react?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I want to learn redux and redux toolkit but I get a problem. I dont know how I fix It.

I only want to store any Items in the users store.

In my example this 2 Items:

id: '1'
username: input

store.js

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import userReducer from './usersSlice';

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    users: userReducer
  },
})

export default store;
```

usersSlicer.js

```
import { createEntityAdapter, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const todoAdapter = createEntityAdapter();
export const todoSelector = todoAdapter.getSelectors(state => state.users);

const initialState = {

}

const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'users',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addUser: todoAdapter.addOne
  }
});

export const { addUser } = usersSlice.actions
export default usersSlice.reducer
```

Form.js

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { addUser } from '../store/usersSlice';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
const Form = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [input, setInput] = useState('');

  dispatch(addUser({
    id: '1',
    username: input
  }));

  return (
    <form>
      <input type="text" onChange={e => setInput(e.target.value)}/>
    </form>
  )
};

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem: Initial State

```
console.log("initial", todoAdapter.getInitialState());
```

The above statement shows you the initial state created by the `todoAdapter`.  It is an object with an array property `ids` and an object property `entities`.  It looks like:

```
initial {ids: Array(0), entities: Object}
```

Calling `addOne` on the `todoAdapter` is searching for the key `1` in the `entities` property.

Your slice's initial state is an empty object `{}`.  It does not have `ids` or `entities`.  When the `addOne` function searches for id `1` in `state.entities`, you get the error *"Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '1' in undefined"* because `state.entities` is `undefined`.

#### Solution

There is a very simple solution for this.  You can set your slice's initial state to the one provided by the entity adapter.

```
const usersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "users",
  initialState: todoAdapter.getInitialState(),
  reducers: {
    addUser: todoAdapter.addOne
  }
});
```